# How to pass two PHP variables in HTML button onClick function?

Tags: php, html, onclick

I need to pass these two variables in my HTML button.

```
$value['_id']
$sellerInfo[0]['City']
```

The HTML is:

```
<button id='myBtn' onclick='showproduct()'>Pending</button>
```

I have tried with this code:

```
<button id='myBtn' onclick='showproduct("<?php echo $value['_id'];?> , <?php echo $sellerInfo[0]['City']; ?>  ")'>Pending</button>
```

I'm getting an error the second parameter is `undefined`.

How can I pass the two variables in `showproduct()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quotes are messed.

Change your code to this:

```
<button id='myBtn' onclick='showproduct("<?php echo $value['_id'];?>" , "<?php echo $sellerInfo[0]['City']; ?>")'>Pending</button>
```

Comment: avoiding the double quotes gives an error  **ReferenceError: PRD8798454 is not defined**

Comment: Can you please show me the instruction context, 2 or 3 lines before and after it ?

Comment: solved the issue onclick='showproduct("variable1","variable2")'

Comment: You were passing only one parameter, because of the double quotes. Your call looked like `showproduct("100, NYC")` whereas it should have been `showproduct(100, "NYC")`

Comment: yeah. that was the reason :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<button id='myBtn' onclick='showproduct("<?php echo $value['_id'];?>" , "<?php echo $sellerInfo[0]['City']; ?>")'>Pending</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try these tricks in your onClick function from this example

```
<i class="fa fa-times pl-5 in_time_late_approve" onclick='in_time_late_approve("<?php echo $key ?>", "<?php echo $employee_attendance_item->attendance_in_time ?>")' style="color:green; cursor:pointer" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```